# MYSQL - Inner join with select statement to fetch Sum

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join

Right now I have the following query:

```
SELECT
ui.email,
ui.userid,
SUM(ep.earnPoints),
ep.add_date
from earn_points as ep 
INNER JOIN user_info as ui on ep.userid on ui.userid 
where DATE(rc.add_date) = '2012-03-22';
```

I want to fetch total no of earnPoints of individual uses with their respective emails

So my final output should be like following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
userid      email                   earnPoints      date        
1           testuser@gmail.com      45              2012-03-22
2           testuser123@gmail.com   10              2012-03-22
3           testuser145@gmail.com   18              2012-03-22
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is there any error in your query?

Comment: it gives me output like

-----------------------------------------------------------
    userid    email                  earnPoints    date        
 1 testuser@gmail.com   73            2012-03-22
-----------------------------------------------------------

though i have fetched in while loop it gives me single record with sum of all points of all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
ui.email,
ui.userid,
SUM(ep.earnPoints),
ep.add_date
from earn_points as ep 
INNER JOIN user_info as ui on ep.userid = ui.userid 
where DATE(rc.add_date) = '2012-03-22' Group By ui.email,ui.userid,ep.add_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only missing group by:

```
SELECT
ui.email,
ui.userid,
SUM(ep.earnPoints),
ep.add_date
from earn_points as ep 
INNER JOIN user_info as ui on ep.userid on ui.userid 
where DATE(rc.add_date) = '2012-03-22'
Group By ui.email,ui.userid,ep.add_date
```